# Fontes instaladas não sendo exibidas em versões antigas do IReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, font

Apenas para fins de catalogação, estive envolvido em um problema com a instalação de fontes em versões antigas do IReport (3.7.2 e 4.0.2), e o problema era que ao instalar uma fonte textual a mesma era listada no menu de configuração mas ao criar um novo relatório, a opção da nova fonte não era exibida no combobox de fontes disponíveis.

Demorei bastante para descobrir o problema tendo em vista que aparentemente ninguém mais teve esse problema além de mim, mesmo nos fóruns internacionais e pelo fato de não haver documentação suficiente da ferramenta. Vou postar a solução aqui como resposta e espero que ajude quem estiver passando por esse problema também.

Instalando a fonte 'N&D font' de exemplo:
[Imagem da instalação N&D font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbj2g.png)

Como resultado atual a fonte não aparece no combobox de fontes: [Problema fonte não aparece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikaG5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Para que a fonte apareça, é necessário dois passos a mais:

1 - exportar a fonte como uma extensão .jar no menu de configuração de fontes:
[Exportar como extensão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKpdr.png)

2- incluir a extensão .jar gerada no menu de configuração do classpath(não marcar reloadable):
[Incluir fonte no classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAd5q.png)

Agora sim a fonte é exibida.
Segue o resultado final esperado:
[Fonte sendo exibida corretamente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn1cd.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).